# iOS - Animation CGAffineTransformTranslate - Hides under Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uinavigationbar, cgaffinetransform

I'm doing an animation where I'm moving and scaling an image at the same time. 
I want to move the image onto a toolbar button in the top navigation bar. It scales down to zero as it does this so it looks like the image is being saved to that location....similar to what happens when you download a song in iTunes on the iPhone.
My scaling and the translation are working fine, however the image disappears under the navigation bar. I want it to translate on top of the navigation bar and then disappear.

Does anyone know how I can tell my animation not to go under the navigation bar?
My code is below. 
Thanks
Brian

```
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(160, -160);
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
CGAffineTransform transform =  CGAffineTransformConcat(scale, translate);
//transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 20);

[UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveAndScaleAnimation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

imageView.transform = transform;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about the navigation bar? Maybe you're talking about the status bar.

Comment: Yep. Its the top navigation bar that I'm talking about, not the status bar. My solution was to set the opacity of the image so that it disappears, rather than sitting on top of the navigation bar.